# Database drop: command not found Informix on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, informix, heredoc

I am trying to run a source code to edit a database in Informix with the following line:
 drop table if exists tablename;

However I got an error message:
 drop: command not found

I am trying to run a source code to edit a database in Informix with the following line:
 drop table if exists tablename;

However I got an error message:
 drop: command not found

### I am new to database and Ubuntu so this is not straight forward for me. Please help how to resolve this. thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:.
#UTC
dt="2016-09-01 00:00:00.00000"
# dt=`date -u +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.00000"` 
# non-UTC
# dt=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.00000"`

echo ""
echo "Building DB"
dbaccess sysmaster - <<EOF1

drop database if exists iot;
create database iot in datadbs1 with buffered log ; 
EOF1

echo ""
echo "Building row types, tables, and other objects" dbaccess iot - 


drop table if exists sensors;
drop table if exists sensors_vti;
...
```

Comment: @Simonare has the right problem diagnosed, you have incorrectly written the drop table commands as they are outside the echo.  The correct final lines from above would be

`
echo "drop table if exists sensors" | dbaccess iot -
echo "drop table if exists sensors_vti" | dbaccess iot -`

or a variant of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use db commands inside bash (directly)

```
drop table if exists sensors;
drop table if exists sensors_vti;
```

the format you need to use is

```
dbaccess sysmaster - <<EOF
    drop database if exists iot;
    create database iot in datadbs1 with buffered log ; 
EOF
```

alternatively

```
echo "drop database if exists iot;create database iot in datadbs1 with buffered log ;" | dbaccess sysmaster
```